# IDE strongly integrated with leiningen for exceptions

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Are there any IDE or editors integrated with leiningen, such that leiningen tasks can be dispatched by them, and if or when they throw an exception in your code, they jump you to the source file and line where the exception arises?

For example, I would like to `lein test` or `lein compile` upon saving a source file, and jump to the offending line of code if an exception is thrown during the task's execution.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, [Cursive](https://cursive-ide.com/) does that very well. It's a plugin for [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).

[image]

Now, that's only possible when REPLing from within IntelliJ, and I don't think it does auto-compile on save, but that's possible with just one keyboard shortcut.

As for calling leiningen tasks from the IDE, yes you can via the "External Tools" feature. But you can also run tests from the REPL by invoking the test functions.

Comment: Thanks, lets see what else comes up, for those who do not (yet) favor IntelliJ

Comment: I think given the time passed that would be unhelpful to the community @tar

Answer (score 2):

Emacs with [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) displays
the exception when you eval something (e.g., your file, `C-c C-k`) and you can hit
`Enter` to visit the trigger.

[image]

Many provided shortcuts let you run tasks like *test*.
[Here](https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactive_programming/) is
a list of CIDER's bindings.  You can also see Clojure mode bindings right in Emacs
with `C-h RET`.

And, you can see many of the other CIDER/task commands by simply pressing `C-c`, if you install [helm-descbinds](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-descbinds).  Most of the CIDER bindings happen to be shown in the right column.

[image]

Lastly, you can type `M-x cider-` to see a list of many (~100) unbound commands.

[image]